# What does this ensemble of symbols mean: $C^{2}(\bar{\Omega})$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For Context, I'll provid the sentence in which the symbols lie; it sets up the conditions for a proof of Green's Identity.

Let $\Omega \subset \Re^n$ be domain with a smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$. Let u,v $\in $ $C^{2}(\bar{\Omega})$, where $\bar{\Omega}$ denotes the closure of $\Omega$.

What does this ensemble of symbols mean: $C^{2}(\bar{\Omega})$ ?

Comment: Continuously twice-differentiable on some neighborhood of the closure of the domain $\Omega$.

Comment: The neighborhood part added to ensure openness I assume?

Comment: Yes, an open set to make sense of partial derivatives along the boundary.

Comment: Eyy thanks a lot. Green's Identity makes use of the Laplacian, so having twice-differentiability as a given makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Adams-Fournier, p. 80]:

$C^j(\bar{\Omega})$ denotes the closed subspace of $C^j_b(\Omega)$ consisting of functions having bounded, uniformly continuous derivatives up to order $j$ on $\Omega$ normed by 
$$
\|\phi\|_{C^j(\bar{\Omega})} = \max_{0 \leq \alpha \leq j} \sup_{x\in \Omega} |D^{\alpha}\phi(x)|.
$$

Here $C^j_b(\Omega)$ is the space of functions having bounded, continuous derivatives up to order $j$ on $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you kindly; I'll be looking at that book as well.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

$C^2 (\bar{\Omega})$ represents the $C^2$ functions on this domain i.e. functions whose second derivatives (both pure and mixed) exist and are continuous.

Edit: As Shifrin points out below, this is incorrect.

Comment: No, that would be $C^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: Ah you’re right!